# C# copy, paste a form in a Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2005, resources

I want to create a new form that is almost a duplicate of a dialog I already have in my project.  I don't want to waste time recreate most of the form scratch if I don't have to.

I copy, then paste it into my project, and rename it from `Copy of Original`.cs to `NewItem.cs`.

When I goto rebuild my solution, I get an **error**.

```
The item "obj\Debug\Control.Forms.NewUser.resources" was specified more
than once in the "Resources" parameter.  
Duplicate items are not supported by the "Resources" parameter.
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a way to fix the problem?

Comment: not yet, I'm still having the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have some local resource stored in a file Called Original.resx

When you copied the dialog it copied this file but did not rename it (this should not happen though). See if you have a .resx file beneath your Copy Of Original.cs in the Solution Explorer. If so rename this also.

Might be worth performing a Clean (right-click on the Project or Solution) anyway to clear out the obj and bin folders, then try a recompile.

Comment: the Copy Of Original.resx file did refactor it's name when I renamed the Original.cs to New.cs

Comment: I have a few controls that i set the 'GenerateMembers' property to false, that is why it created the resx file to begin with.  Inside the resx file the controls have a 'PublicKeyToken' attribute which is the same in both files. I wonder if that is the problem.

Comment: Setting GenerateMembers propery to false should not drive the creation of a .RESX file.

Check that each of your classes are correctly named in the .cs and designer.cs. I have seen before that when you make a copy of a form and go into the code to change its class name, Visual Studio re-factors all the code and changes the name of the class in the original form.cs file also (thus creating a duplicate with the new name).

Answer (score 2):

Old question but I'll answer for future googlers since OP claimed that accepted answer didn't resolve the problem.

Problem is that `NewItem.cs` still contains a class with the same name as `Original.cs`. This happens when file name and class name are different (unlike Eclipse for Java, Visual Studio allows that in C# projects). Copy-pasting appends "Copy of " prefix to the file name and rename file feature is not intelligent enough to figure out that renaming the class would be appropriate in such case.

To fix the error, the class in duplicated project item has to be renamed. I say item instead of file because in the case of WinForms stuff, that means two files: one that solution explorer displays by default (right click -> show code or F7 if you are greeted by visual designer) and the .designer.cs. There is no need to modify .resx AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

When create the copy of Original form, VS don't change the original namespace ( in your case, it's still "Original"). So, just change this duplicated namespace(in "Copy of Original") into somethings unique.